# In DirEd, how can I copy the directory path of a filename?

Tags: directories, filenames

I have this function

```
(defun my/dired-copy-dirname-as-kill ()
  "Copy the current directory into the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new default-directory))
```

, but this only copies the linked path, not the physical path.

If I use that function I get `~/`, instead of `/home/quux/`

I only want to copy the directory part of the whole path to the filename.

Comment: This question (or at least your function, save for its name) has nothing to do with dired.

Answer (score 0):

See:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `expand-file-name`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `file-truename` (if you also want to chase symlinks)